# using HtmlAgilityPack to select innerHtml

Tags: c#, html, vb.net, html-agility-pack

let say i have follow html document

```
<div class=" wrap_body text_align_left" style="">
  <div class="some"> hello </div>
  <div class="someother"> world </div>
  hello world
</div>
```

i want to extract this

```
      <div class="some"> hello </div>
      <div class="someother"> world </div>
      hello world
```

what is best way to extract using HtmlAgilityPack with c# or vb.net?
this is my code until done but some struggle .
thanks!

```
For Each no As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In docs.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'wrap_body')]")
    Dim attr As String = no.GetAttributeValue("wrap_body", "")

Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a sample for getting Inner Html

```
var html =
        @"<body>
            <div class='wrap_body text_align_left' style=''>
  <div class='some'> hello </div>
  <div class='someother'> world </div>
  hello world
</div>
        </body>";

        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

        var htmlNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body/div");

        foreach (var node in htmlNodes)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(node.InnerHtml);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SelectNodes` of `DocumentNode` metod to retrieve specific nodes from html.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string htmlContent = File.ReadAllText(@"Your path to html file"); ;

        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();

        doc.LoadHtml(htmlContent);

        var innerContent = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/div").FirstOrDefault().InnerHtml;

        Console.WriteLine(innerContent);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]